# How to clear the HTML content of some id in jquery?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, smarty

I'm using smarty template, php and ajax. I've following code snippet from my smarty template:

```
<td align="left" id="subject_container" colspan="2" valign="top">
    <form>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" border="0" width="68%"> 
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                        {if $subject_details}  
                          Subjects
                        </td>
                        {assign var='i' value=0}
                        {foreach from=$all_subjects item=subjects}
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" width="150">
                        {foreach from=$subject_details item=subject} 
                        {if $subject.cs_subject_id==$subjects.subject_id}{$subjects.subject_name}{/if}
                        {/foreach}
                        </td>
                        {assign var='i' value=$i+1}
                      {/foreach}
                      </tr>
                      {/if}
                    </table>
                  </form>
                </td>
```

The jQuery function is like as follows :

```
function get_subjects_by_class(class_id) { 
    var field_id = 'subjects';

    $.ajax({
                url: "teacher_details.php",
          type: "POST",
                data: {'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'get_assigned_subject_list', 'class_id':class_id},  
                success: function(data) {
                $('#subject_container').append(data);
                }
      });
    }
```

Now what I want to achieve is every time the function gets called the content of `id="subject_container"` should get clear and replaced with the new content which will come as a response from php file. I googled for it but couldn't get the satisfactory solution. Can anyone help me out in this regard? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
  $.ajax({
                url: "teacher_details.php",
          type: "POST",
                data: {'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'get_assigned_subject_list', 'class_id':class_id},  
                success: function(data) {
                //$('#subject_container').append(data);
$('#subject_container').html(data);//<-- here
                }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your magic did it for me. You have saved my precious time.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$('#subject_container').append(data);
```

to

```
$('#subject_container').html(data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your magic did it for me. You have saved my precious time.